# Why is there a a nose-up pitching tendency during a forward slip in a Cessna 172?

Tags: aerodynamics, cessna-172, sideslip

Why is there a tendency for the nose to pitch-up during a forward slip in a Cessna 172 (According to the TC Flight training manual)?

Quote:
"If full rudder is used, considerable aileron pressure may be needed to maintain the bank. There will also be a tendency for the nose to pitch up as a result of the banked attitude and rudder input"

Comment: I'd suggesting including in the actual question the specific aircraft where you have noticed this.  PS t-tailed aircraft often pitch nose-down in a slip.  Might be related.

Comment: Can't say I've ever noticed that myself, but I'd be interested to see what that manual says.

Comment: It sounds like the manual is saying when you are banked, a yawing tendency is also a tendency for the nose to rise higher above the horizon.  I suspect that there may be more to the real story though, i.e. there may be some tendency for the aircraft to actually rotate about the pitch axis.

Comment: Never noticed that in my Cardinal. Altho I have done it so often I may not notice it and just push the nose down a little as put in full rudder and opposite aileron to lose altitude quick while on final. The plane straightens right up when controls are released.

Comment: What is a “TC Flight training manual”?

Comment: Mike Sowson if you don’t know that I can’t really see any reasonable or understandable reason for you commenting on this post.

Comment: I think what is a "TC Flight training manual" is a good comment.  Why doesn't it say Cessna 172 on it?  Pushing into a forward slip greatly increases drag.  The result is the plane slows and the nose *drops*.  I would strongly recommend actually doing a few with an instructor.  The 172 is ingeniously designed plane that handles beautifully in forward slips.  At 65 knots, trimmed, very little pitching was noticed (even with flaps), and plenty of opposite aileron was available.

Answer (score 3):

It is because of opposite rudder in the bank.  In the forward slip and due to angle of bank the rudder input will push the tail down somewhat resulting in the nose coming up as it rotates around the normal axis which is now inclined due to the bank.  This is easier to see looking at a model plane.

Comment: Remember to think relative to the plane, not the ground.  Rudder input *yaws* the plane, it does not change AoA.  Pitching oscillations may occur due to drag turbulence acting on the *horizontal stabilizer*.  They are more noticeable with flaps extended.